# No puedo hacer un insert desde angular (front) laravel (back)

Tags: php, laravel-5, angular, angular-cli

Tengo el siguiente metodo para insertar

public function store(Request $request){

```
    // recoger los datos por post
    $json = $request->input('json',null);
    $params = json_decode($json);

    $params_array = json_decode($json, true);
    // validar los datos
    $validate = \Validator::make($params_array,[
        'inv_nombre'=>'required',
        'inv_apellPater'=>'required',
        'inv_apellMater'=>'required',
        'inv_cedula'=>'required',
        'inv_correo'=>'required',
        'inv_telefono'=>'required',
        'fk_ciu_codigo'=>'required',
        'fk_ent_codigo'=>'required'
    ]);

    if($validate->fails()){

        return response()->json($validate->errors(),400);
    }

    $investigador = new T_investigador();
    $investigador ->inv_nombre = $params->inv_nombre;
    $investigador ->inv_apellPater = $params ->inv_apellPater;
    $investigador ->inv_apellMater = $params ->inv_apellMater;
    $investigador ->inv_cedula = $params ->inv_cedula;
    $investigador ->inv_correo = $params ->inv_correo;
    $investigador ->inv_telefono = $params ->inv_telefono;
    $investigador ->fk_ciu_codigo = $params ->fk_ciu_codigo;
    $investigador ->fk_ent_codigo = $params ->fk_ent_codigo;

    $investigador->save();

    $mensaje = "Se agrego el investigador";

    $respuesta = response::json([
        'messaje' => $mensaje,
        'data' => $investigador
    ],201);

     return $respuesta; 

}
```

Al momento de intentar guardar el formulario me sale el siguiente error

"count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Alguien puede ayudarme por favor necesito que me inserte, los parametros son enviados desde un servicio en Angular que recibe el form

Muchas gracias